# How to properly give argument to docker entrypoint when building a container (docker run ...)?

Tags: docker

My goal is to share properly an docker image between 2 servers. 
I need to give the name of the hostname when creating my containers.

How can I give an arg to docker run command that will take account by the entrypoint script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option **e** of docker run command like this :

```
docker run -it -e ARG1=foo -e ARG2=bar ubuntu
```

It the previous example, we define 2 args called ARG1 and ARG2.

*For the hostname, when you specify option --hostname of Docker run, it will set a variable in env HOSTNAME which can be used.*